# При запуске и обновлении страницы некорректно отображаются данные значений с ion.rangeslider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть фильтр выбора цены — минимального и максимального значения, использую ion.rangeslider. Вот в чем вопрос: как сделать, чтобы при загрузке страницы, открытии фильтра в полях `min` и `max` уже стояли значения? Сейчас у меня они пустые и только после действия выбора цен (движения ползунка), значения появляются. Как это исправить? Спасибо.

Пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $range = $(".range_slider"),
    $min = $(".min-price"),
    $max = $(".max-price");

  var track = function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      from = $this.data("from"),
      to = $this.data("to");
    $min.text(from + ' руб.');
    $max.text(to + ' руб');
  };

  $range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: 10000,
    max: 10000000,
    from: 26000,
    to: 900000,
    hide_from_to: true,
onload: function(data){
    $min.val(data.fromNumber);
    $max.val( data.toNumber);
}
  });

  $range.on("change", track);

  $('select').styler();
});
```

```css
.irs-slider {
  top: 29px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(51, 45, 46);
  background: $stack-color;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $stack-color 0%, $stack-color 20%, $stack-color 100%);
  border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.irs-bar {
  height: 10px;
  top: 33px;
  border-top: 1px solid $stack-color;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $stack-color;
  background: $stack-color;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, $stack-color 0%, $stack-color 100%);
}

.irs-min,
.irs-max {
  display: none;
}

.sl-wrap {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.min-price {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid rgb(225, 225, 225);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: $base-color;
  font-family: $Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.max-price {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid rgb(225, 225, 225);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: $base-color;
  font-family: $Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/js/ion-rangeSlider/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<div class="range-slider">
  <div class="sl-wrap">
    <input type="text" class="range_slider" id="range_slider" value="" placeholder="" />
  </div>
  <div class="min-price">

  </div>
  <div class="max-price">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно объединить все действия в одну функцию и присвоить её к `onStart` и `onChange`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $range = $(".range_slider"),
    $min = $(".min-price"),
    $max = $(".max-price"),
    ionValues = function(data) {
      $min.text(data.from + ' руб.');
      $max.text(data.to + ' руб');
    }

  $range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: 10000,
    max: 10000000,
    from: 26000,
    to: 900000,
    hide_from_to: true,
    onStart: ionValues,
    onChange: ionValues
  });
});
```

```css
.irs-slider {
  top: 29px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(51, 45, 46);
  background: $stack-color;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $stack-color 0%, $stack-color 20%, $stack-color 100%);
  border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.irs-bar {
  height: 10px;
  top: 33px;
  border-top: 1px solid $stack-color;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $stack-color;
  background: $stack-color;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, $stack-color 0%, $stack-color 100%);
}

.irs-min,
.irs-max {
  display: none;
}

.sl-wrap {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.min-price {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid rgb(225, 225, 225);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: $base-color;
  font-family: $Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.max-price {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid rgb(225, 225, 225);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: $base-color;
  font-family: $Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/js/ion-rangeSlider/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<div class="range-slider">
  <div class="sl-wrap">
    <input type="text" class="range_slider" id="range_slider" value="" placeholder="" />
  </div>
  <div class="min-price">

  </div>
  <div class="max-price">
  </div>

</div>
```